# Picklist Choice Set - New Resource Value unavailable

Tags: picklist, screen-flow, variable

I hope someone can help...

I'm creating a Screen Flow to create a new Opportunity with a Picklist Choice Set in one of the Trailblazer Playgrounds.

I've created a StageName Picklist Choice Set and I can see it in the Toolbox (lefthand side screen - highlighted on a screenshot below).

I selected to create an Opportunity record and when I try to select the Picklist Choice Set I created from the Variables, it's not visible on the Variables list!

I've tried to create an alternative Picklist Choice Set from the "Create Records" screen but the Choice Set simply won't show up on the list for it to be mapped with the "StageName".

I've tried refreshing the page, re-creating the Flow and it won't show up.

When I debug the Flow, I can clearly see the StageName values ok (2nd screenshot below)

Am I missing something obvious?

Many thanks for the time and help in advance!

Lakis

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]